# Is it possible to use different dialects on different fields?

Tags: python, dialect

I am reading CSV file with python and for some fields I want to remove escape char (`'aaa/bb'` to `aaabb`) and for some fields leave it without a change.

for example:
input:`13,0,0,"0",false,"test\\file",-1,-1,1314570610162,13,"1","Danny","name\\Mary"`
expected output:`13,0,0,"0",false,"testfile",-1,-1,1314570610162,13 ,"1","Danny","name\Mary"`

This is the code I am using:

```
csv.register_dialect('mydialect', escapechar='\\')
dialect = csv.get_dialect('mydialect')
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect=dialect)
writer.writerow
(
    (
        <row to write>
    )
)
```

Can I use several dialects on the same row? how? another idea?

Comment: I don't see an escape char here. Can you provide a sample row before/after your intended transformation?

Comment: how are you reading the CSV. Please provide more context.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide more sample data to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it. You don't need to have multiple dialects, they describe the *csv file* layout. You want to remove characters within certain fields, which is easily done before writing your output.

Something like this should be good:

```
reader = csv.reader(yourFileHandle)
writer = csv.writer(outputFileHandle)
for row in reader:
    row[5] = row[5].replace(r'\','')
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [`escapechar`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar) if quoting is not `QUOTE_NONE` and `doublequote` is True (default).

```
>>> import csv, sys
>>> w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> w.writerow([1,'"ab"','c,','d e', 'f', 'g\\'])
1,"""ab""","c,",d e,f,g\
>>> w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar='\\')
>>> w.writerow([1,'"ab"','c,','d e', 'f', 'g\\'])
1,\"ab\",c\,,d e,f,g\\
>>> w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, doublequote=False,escapechar='\\')
>>> w.writerow([1,'"ab"','c,','d e', 'f', 'g\\'])
1,\"ab\","c,",d e,f,"g\"
```